# simplejson newline

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send to the client with django python a json string with newlines:

```
        string += u'hello\n'
        data = {'data':string}
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), mimetype = 'application/json')
```

On the browser side i get the string and open it in a text editor but see 'hello\n' .  is it because simplejson escapes the newlines?  How would pass it as a newline instead of the two character '\n'?

Comment: Looks correct to me, what is your exact problem? JavaScript understands `\n` as a newline escape as well.

Comment: I want to use the returned json as nicely formatted css, but when i open up the data at the browser side, it doesn't replace the '\n' with newlines...

Comment: And it shouldn't! You are displaying string literals, not their values. You could try and insert `<br/>` tags where needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see `\n` in a text editor, that's because you haven't decoded it. Once you decode it as JSON in the browser it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is the escape code used by JSON to represent a newline. When you decode the JSON it will be turned back into a newline character.

[image]

Comment: I am pretty certain that the OP understood that just fine. His problem is on the browser / JavaScript side of things. Moreover, the `\n` newline escape has *nothing* to do with `dict`.